# How to restrict access to specific secrets in POD ( POD Should access only to specific secrets used by the given application)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-rbac

I want to access specific secret from POD , I dont want POD to have access to other secrets(which are not needed).

I  have created an service account with no access to secrets ( not even "get").

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: no-access-to-secrets
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: no-access-to-secrets
rules:
- apiGroups:  [""] 
  verbs:  [""]
  resources:
    - ""
  resourceNames:
    - ""
      
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: no-access-to-secrets
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: no-access-to-secrets
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: no-access-to-secrets
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

**Expectation**: I have assigned this service account to POD, so POD should complain or failed to start due to lack of access to the secret.

```yaml
...
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-name
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: no-access-to-secrets
envFrom:
  - secretRef:
     name: my-secret

...
```

but to my surprise, the pod is started with reading a secret as env vars. So confused, help me  here.

I dont know where I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your role/rolebinding will be applicable to your application that is running inside your pod.

Comment: You need to determine the role/rolebinding of the user/identity who created the pod.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Agreed that role/rolebinding helps in restricting access to k8s resources using apiserver calls.
But how can i restrict access to secrets on POD creation time or scaledup scenarios ?
Anyway I will try your creating POD with sa.

Comment: Hi, Did creating a pod with a SA work?

Comment: yes I am able to create a POD with SA Account , POD starts up and working fine. but SA dont have access to secrets used by POD Spec.

Comment: did you find it out? perhaps it would be good to post an answer